# Find maximum from NDSolve output

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, mathematical-optimization

Here is my code:

```
rawdata = http://pastebin.com/fgeZrSCp (* I hope pastebin is OK *)

f[x_] := Interpolation[rawdata, InterpolationOrder->1][(x + 1)*10]
  (* just creating a function with the data *)
d = 0.05;
T = 0.8;
wn = 2 Pi/T;
wd = wn*Sqrt[1 - d^2];

sol = 
  NDSolve[{xx''[t] + 2 d wn*xx'[t] + wn^2 xx[t] == -f[t], xx[0] == 0, xx'[0] == 0}, xx, 
    {t, 0, 65}, MaxSteps -> 500000];
Plot[Evaluate[xx[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 65}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot of the solution]

My goal is to get the maximum value of `Abs[xx[t]]`. How can I do this in an  efficient way?

Note that `d` and `T` can change. In this particular example the maximum should be around 0.052.

Context: Structural Dynamics, I'm trying to find a "response spectrum".

Comment: Well, you can't use NDSolve if you do not have a numerical value for d and T. So, once these are set, and you get your solution xx[t] from NDSolve, then you can use many of Mathematica maximum related functions, may be NMaxValue migth do it. "gives the maximum value of f with respect to x." http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NMaxValue.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(*just creating a function with the data*)
d = 0.05;
T = 0.8;
wn = 2 Pi/T;
wd = wn*Sqrt[1 - d^2]; 
f[x_] := Interpolation[rawdata, InterpolationOrder -> 1][(x + 1)*10] ; 
sol = NDSolve[{xx''[t] + 2 d wn*xx'[t] + wn^2 xx[t] == -f[t], xx[0] == 0, 
                xx'[0] == 0}, xx, {t, 0, 65}, MaxSteps -> 500000];
Show[Plot[Abs[xx[t]] /. sol, {t, 0, 65}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
           Point@{t /. #[[2]], #[[1]]} &@ NMaximize[{Abs[xx[t]] /. sol[[1]], 1 < t < 65}, t]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> NMaximize always attempts to find a global maximum of f subject to the constraints given.
>
> If f and cons are linear, NMaximize can always find global maxima, over both real and integer values.
>
> Otherwise, NMaximize may sometimes find only a local maximum.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I have to iterate through T to plot a curve of the maxima found and it's taking a year.  Would it be possible to make my code run faster? (Should I open a new question for that?)

Comment: @IvánVladimirGonzálezBustos `sol = ParametricNDSolve[{xx''[t] + 
      2 d 2 Pi /T xx'[t] + (2 Pi/T)^2 xx[t] == -f[t], xx[0] == 0, 
    xx'[0] == 0}, xx, {t, 0, 65}, {T}, MaxSteps -> 500000];
ss = Table[
  NMaxValue[{Abs[xx[T][t]] /. sol[[1]], 1 < t < 65}, t], {T, .55, 
   3, .125}]
ListPlot[ss, Joined -> True]`

Comment: @IvánVladimirGonzálezBustos For T < .5 the maxima found is unreliable